# Divisibility based on central binomial coefficients

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

For some prime $p$, it is a standard approach based on Kummer's criterion to bound the number of positive integers $n<X$ for some parameter $X$, such that $p\nmid \binom{2n}{n}$. However, if we take some fixed positive integer $M$ and take the same problem of bounding number of positive integers $n<X$ such that $p\nmid \binom{2nM}{nM}$, then has there been any literature on this?
Also, has there been any work on the problem of bounding number of $n<X$ such that $p\mid \binom{2nM}{nM}$?
Thanks in advance for any assistance.